# actionListener doesn't work after JButton is recreated

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm coding an UNO card game, I created an array with JButtons that will change in size, the JButtons represent the players hand and all the different cards in it. When the buttons is created for the first time everything is working, but when I add one card and expand the array, the buttons actionListener is broken. I think that when the buttons is created for the second time the actionListners is created locally and not globally. I have no idea how to fix the problem, so please help! xd

```
// playerHandButtons = the array with the buttons that is recreated
// playerHand = a stack that contains the players cards in the hand
```

```
// when the array is created for the first time

JButton [] playerHandButtons = new JButton[7]; 
// you start with 7 cards
public void createArray() {

        JButton[] playerHandButtons = new JButton[playerHand.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < playerHandButtons .length; i++) {
            playerHandButtons [i] = new JButton("" + playerHand.elementAt(i));
            player.add(playerHandButtons [i]);
            playerHandButtons [i].addActionListener(this);
        }
    }
```

```
//  player = is the panel that displays all the cards

    public void createHand() {

        player.removeAll();
        player.repaint();
        player.revalidate();

        JButton[] playerHandButtons = new JButton[playerHand.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < playerHandButtons .length; i++) {
            playerHandButtons [i] = new JButton("" + playerHand.elementAt(i));
            player.add(playerHandButtons [i]);
            playerHandButtons [i].addActionListener(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is strange: `player.add(playerHandGUI[i])` -- why are you adding `playerHandGUI[i]` to player and not the button that you just created? Where do you add that button to the GUI? I think that we're dealing with a likely typographical error.

Comment: playerHandButtons was called playerHandGUI I changed the name in the question to clarify. I edited it out in the question and it is still the same problem. Thanks for notifying it!

Comment: Can you post the code for the action listener and the code that adds and removes cards ?

Comment: That is not enough context to find the issue. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.

It kind of surprise me that even the first time this code may work, because `JButton[] playerHandButtons = new JButton[playerHand.size()];` in the `createArray()` method create a local variable that should be eligible for garbage collection as soon as you leave the method.

If you want to keep reference of the *buttons* you create, you should just use `playerHandButtons = new JButton[playerHand.size()];` which will assign a new array to the field playerHandButtons.

Same goes to for the `createHand()` method.

There could be other solutions too, but much depend on the *listener* class.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I found another solution instead. I created an array that contains a maximum, instead of creating an array that will change size it will only display the same amount of buttons that there is cards in playerHand and in that way the actionListeners will stay.